# Filter aws ec2 snapshots by current date

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, snapshot

How to filter AWS EC2 snapshots by current day?

I'm filtering snapshots by tag:Disaster_Recovery with value:Full, using python code below, and I need also filter it by the current day.

```py
import boto3
region_source = 'us-east-1'

client_source = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region_source)

# Getting all snapshots as per specified filter
def get_snapshots():
    response = client_source.describe_snapshots(
        Filters=[{'Name': 'tag:Disaster_Recovery', 'Values': ['Full']}]
    )
    return response["Snapshots"]


print(*get_snapshots(), sep="\n")
```

Comment: use the start-time filter. For values use something from the python datetime package. https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_snapshots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could do the trick:

```py
import boto3
from datetime import date

region_source = 'us-east-1'


client_source = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region_source)

# Getting all snapshots as per specified filter
def get_snapshots():
    response = client_source.describe_snapshots(
        Filters=[{'Name': 'tag:Disaster_Recovery', 'Values': ['Full']}]
    )
    snapshotsInDay = []
    for snapshots in response["Snapshots"]:
       if(snapshots["StartTime"].strftime('%Y-%m-%d') == date.isoformat(date.today())):
           snapshotsInDay.append(snapshots)
    return snapshotsInDay

print(*get_snapshots(), sep="\n")
```

After reading the [docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_snapshots) the rest is a simple date comparision

Comment: `print(datetime.date.today())` gives a result `2019-08-21` and ["StartTime"] has `2019-08-21 05:26:43.510000+00:00` format, so comparision did't match.

Comment: In this case it will first apply filter with tag than match "StartTime" by today day, and print all snapshots, not only today created snapshots. To fix it, I gues `return response["Snapshots"]` should be replaced by variable where snapshots with current day will be collected.

Comment: Yes, it's partially incomplete, I didn't know what else you wanted to do with the function, but it's just creating a list and returning it. I'll put a more verbose resolution then yours.

Answer (score 1):

solve it, by code below:

```
import boto3
from datetime import date

region_source = 'us-east-1'
client_source = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region_source)

date_today = date.isoformat(date.today())


# Getting all snapshots as per specified filter
def get_snapshots():
    response = client_source.describe_snapshots(
        Filters=[{'Name': 'tag:Disaster_Recovery', 'Values': ['Full']}]
    )
    return response["Snapshots"]


# Getting snapshots were created today
snapshots = [s for s in get_snapshots() if s["StartTime"].strftime('%Y-%m-%d') == date_today]

print(*snapshots, sep="\n")
```